# MySQL user blocking query slow - social network design

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm working on a small social network but I'm struggling to optimise the blocking part of the design. I have 3 tables blocking, feed and users. It works fine but when I add in blocking the query goes from 16ms or less to over 50ms or higher, which seems like a lot for something simple. In fact without blocking in my hedisql sql the query time is reported as 0ms sometimes as I guess it's below a certain amount of time.

The idea of blocking is that if a user blocks someone else, they won't be able to see their feed posts and the blocked person won't be able to see the blocker.

The part I'm struggling to optimise is:
**LEFT JOIN blocking ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId AND blocking.blockedId = '3' OR blocking.blockerId = '3' AND blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
WHERE blocking.blockerId IS NULL AND blocking.blockedId IS NULL**

Is there a way I can improve on this query without changing the data or is it as good as it will get?

Query I'm trying to optimise:

```
SELECT users.displayName, feed.id, feed.userId, feed.message
FROM feed
INNER JOIN users ON feed.userId = users.id
LEFT JOIN blocking ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId AND blocking.blockedId = '3' OR blocking.blockerId = '3' AND blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
WHERE blocking.blockerId IS NULL AND blocking.blockedId IS NULL
ORDER BY feed.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Blocking table and keys:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blocking` (
  `blockerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blockedId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blockedId`,`blockerId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `userId` (`blockerId`,`blockedId`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `blockedId` FOREIGN KEY (`blockedId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `blockerId` FOREIGN KEY (`blockerId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Feed table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feed` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `userIdCas` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `displayName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
)
```

Explain without blocking:
[image]

Explain with blocking:
[image]

---

Updated query I'm tweaking seems to run a lot faster:

```
FROM feed
FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
INNER JOIN users ON feed.userId = users.id
LEFT JOIN blocking ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId AND blocking.blockedId = '3' OR blocking.blockerId = '3' AND blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
WHERE blocking.blockerId IS NULL AND blocking.blockedId IS NULL
ORDER BY feed.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Can anyone explain why this runs better and why MySQL might not be using the index to start with?

(From Comment)  I changed the query to

```
SELECT  users.displayName, feed.id, feed.userId, feed.message
    FROM  feed FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
    INNER JOIN  users  ON feed.userId = users.id
    LEFT JOIN  blocking  ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId
      AND  blocking.blockedId = '3'
      OR  blocking.blockerId = '3'
      AND  blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
    WHERE  blocking.blockerId IS NULL
      AND  blocking.blockedId IS NULL
    ORDER BY  feed.id DESC
    LIMIT  20;
```

And it seems to run better, could anyone give me a deeper understanding of why?

Comment: I changed the query too:

SELECT users.displayName, feed.id, feed.userId, feed.message
FROM feed
FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
INNER JOIN users ON feed.userId = users.id
LEFT JOIN blocking ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId AND blocking.blockedId = '3' OR blocking.blockerId = '3' AND blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
WHERE blocking.blockerId IS NULL AND blocking.blockedId IS NULL
ORDER BY feed.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```
And it seems to run better, could anyone give me a deeper understanding of why?

Comment: Please consider changing the names blockerId and/or blockedId -- their similarity makes it very difficult to read the queries.

Comment: And what does the `EXPLAIN` say when not using the `FORCE INDEX`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use () around the OR condition  otherwise you could obtain udesidered  result

```
SELECT users.displayName
  , feed.id
  , feed.userId
  , feed.message
FROM feed
INNER JOIN users ON feed.userId = users.id
LEFT JOIN blocking ON blocking.blockerId = feed.userId 
  AND ( blocking.blockedId = '3' OR blocking.blockerId = '3' )
  AND blocking.blockedId = feed.userId
WHERE blocking.blockerId IS NULL AND blocking.blockedId IS NULL
ORDER BY feed.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

For better performance you could try adding a composite index on table

```
table  blocking columns  ( blockerId, blockedId   )
```

and also a composite index on table

```
table  feed columns  (userId,  message, id )
```

Comment: (Looks like a dup column in your index)